# Android Studio Code Not Working?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have some code that I am working on in Android Studio. The goal is to create an app that has a counter that goes up quickly when you press a start button, and once it gets to the desired input you press a stop button and it records how far away you were from the desired value. It's to test reaction time and such. The problem is that whenever I run the app on my phone or the emulator, the app immediately crashes giving the error "Unfortunately, Timer Test has stopped working." Does Anyone know what the problem might be?

The code in the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.ultraman11.timertest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int numCounter = 0;
    public boolean counting = false;

    TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
    TextView difference = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diff);
    EditText numInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numInput);

    public int userInt = Integer.parseInt(numInput.getText().toString());
    public int differenceInt = Math.abs(numCounter - userInt);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void resetButton(View v){
        numCounter = 0;
        difference.setText("Difference: ");
        counter.setText(Integer.toString(0));
    }

    public void startButton(View v){
        counting = true;
        while(counting){
            numCounter++;
        }
    }

    public void stopButton(View v){
        counting = false;
        difference.setText("Difference: " + Integer.toString(differenceInt));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The code in activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:onClick="resetButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numInput"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="startButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numInput"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/numInput"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_below="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="stopButton" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Difference: "
        android:id="@+id/diff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="43dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat error

```
09-10 17:33:45.103: D/AndroidRuntime(3445): Shutting down VM
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445): Process: com.ultraman11.timertest, PID: 3445
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ultraman11.timertest/com.ultraman11.timertest.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at com.ultraman11.timertest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
09-10 17:33:45.104: E/AndroidRuntime(3445):     ... 10 more
09-10 17:33:47.163: I/Process(3445): Sending signal. PID: 3445 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please provide stack trace from LogCat

Comment: Without the stacktrace, we can only scan your code and try to figure out where the issue is. Please help us, help you by posting the stacktrace and relevant information. This is instrumental to make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must **initialize** your views inside the **onCreate()** Method of **Activity.**  I have edited your java file. try this.

```
package com.ultraman11.timertest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int numCounter = 0;
    public boolean counting = false;

    TextView counter;
    TextView difference;
    EditText numInput;

    public int userInt
    public int differenceInt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
        difference = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diff);
        numInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numInput);

        try{
          userInt = Integer.parseInt(numInput.getText().toString());
        }Catch(Exception e){
          userInt = 0;
        }            
        differenceInt = Math.abs(numCounter - userInt);
    }

    public void resetButton(View v){
        numCounter = 0;
        difference.setText("Difference: ");
        counter.setText(Integer.toString(0));
    }

    public void startButton(View v){
        counting = true;
        while(counting){
            numCounter++;
        }
    }

    public void stopButton(View v){
        counting = false;
        difference.setText("Difference: " + Integer.toString(differenceInt));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
package com.ultraman11.timertest;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public int numCounter = 0;
    public boolean counting = false;

    TextView counter;
    TextView difference;
    EditText numInput;

    public int userInt;
    public int differenceInt;

    TimerTask timertask = null;
    Timer timer = null ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
        difference = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diff);
        numInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numInput);
    }

    public void resetButton(View v){
        numCounter = 0;
        difference.setText("Difference: ");
        counter.setText(Integer.toString(0));
        if(timertask!=null){
            timertask.cancel();
            timertask = null;
        }
        if(timer!=null){
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    public void startButton(View v){
        if(timertask!=null){
            timertask.cancel();
            timertask = null;
        }
        if(timer!=null){
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }

        timer = new Timer();
        timertask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                numCounter++;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        counter.setText(Integer.toString(numCounter));
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timertask, 0, 1000);
    }

    public void stopButton(View v){
        if(timertask!=null){
            timertask.cancel();
            timertask = null;
        }
        if(timer!=null){
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }

        try{
              userInt = Integer.parseInt(numInput.getText().toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
          userInt = 0;
        }            
        differenceInt = Math.abs(numCounter - userInt);
        difference.setText("Difference: " + Integer.toString(differenceInt));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(timertask!=null){
            timertask.cancel();
            timertask = null;
        }

        if(timer!=null){
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just updated the main post with the logcat error that I got using your edited code.

Comment: The code now works and the app runs. I just tried adding counter.setText(Integer.toString(numCounter));right under numCounter++; to update the live counter but after it increments to one, it immediately crashes. Any idea why?

Comment: `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
      counter.setText(Integer.toString(numCounter));
     }
    });`  Add this under numCounter++;

Comment: Thank you so much! Was just going to ask if I should use a runnable xD. You've been a great help.

Comment: I upvoted it just doesn't show because I'm a new user.

Comment: hey i have made some changes, check the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You get immediatly in a loop when you hit start because counting is true so it is just increasing numCounter to infty.
Instead of surround the incremental thing with while use something like an AsyncTask to increase your value.

Edit: 
Sorry I didn't got the point that it crashes immedietly, make sure that you initalize your content in the onCreate Method not before calling onCreate ... setContentView()

Comment: I have counting set to false at the beginning. Is it getting set to true from the button function even though I haven't pressed it yet?

Comment: The real problem is how the views are initialized, like mentioned in the edit.

Comment: When initializing my content in the onCreate() method, none of the other code works because that values are not found. (The content I am referring to is the Text and Edit views.)

Comment: Init the userInt and differenceInt also in the onCreate method it should work, because your content is not visible before onCreate is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `findViewById()` before `onCreate()` is called. You need to change:

```
TextView counter;
TextView difference;
EditText numInput;
```

And set them in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
    difference = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diff);
    numInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numInput);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple error that so many people make. Looking at the LogCat, it tells you right there that you need to use Theme.AppCompat or similar. AppCompat needs AppCompat. It isn't compatible with device themes.
All you have to do is open your AndroidManifest.xml and do this:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    ...
</application>
```

And in /res/values/styles.xml add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>  
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- Put any customizations here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```